# How to use a model with multiple other models

Tags: django

This is probably pretty simple but I am having a mental block so help is appreciated. I have a `discussion` app which contains a `Message` model. I want to relate the `Message` to several other models (e.g. `Video`, `Note`, etc.).

I don't feel that it is right to add a field for each model onto the `Message` model but I want the messages to "cascade delete" when the parent object is deleted (e.g. if `Video` is deleted so all related `Message`'s should be deleted as well).

How can I accomplish this?

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    Stores information pertaining to a message.
    """
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='messages'
    )
    message = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='children',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # this seems wrong
    # video = models.FK
    # note = models.FK
    # etc...
```

Comment: But for there has to be some way in which all these models are related. Do they share any common unique keys...??

Comment: Is using [`generic fk`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) not an option?

Comment: Oops.. accidentally deleted that comment. What are the issues that could come from using generic fks?

Comment: Isince I know which models I will be referring to, it may just be that I should have a field for each other model but all but one are left blank. Feels wrong though.

Comment: Here is a good article on generic fks: https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/ .. when to and when not to use them. I will see if anyone else has recommendations.

Comment: `What are the issues that could come from using generic fks?` -- there's a bit of a learning curve but other than that it seems to fit as a solution to your problem. And it will also prevent you from writing so many fk's to message in the future (doesn't scale well this way)

Comment: That was a great article. Thank you! So which approach are you doing then?

Comment: My architecture uses `django-tenant-schemas` where some apps are tenant specific and some apps are shared. I am concerned I do not know enough about generic fks to safely implement it without breaking my database. For that reason I decided to go strictly with 1-to-1 relationships where there may be a slight headache due to repeating code or whatnot but it will not mess up my database. I am going to continue to learn about generic fks for the future though.

Answer (score 0):

> Create sub classes

```
class models(models.Model):
    class message(models.Model):
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this suggestion?

Comment: I am now wondering if I could make a `mixin` for use such as: `class Note(MessageMixin)` and `class Video(MessageMixin)`. This would allow me to delete each object along with the related messages and message data, right?